# Marking duplicate id gives error

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am trying to mark repeated event ids.

```
update event set repeated = 1 where eid in 
(SELECT eid FROM event group by eid HAVING count(eid) > 1);
```

However, I am getting the following response:

```
You can't specify target table 'event' for update in FROM clause
```

Answer (score 2):

You can 'fool' MySQL when using another subquery to cover that up that you can't select from a table that you are updating

```
update event 
set repeated = 1 
where eid in 
(
    select * from 
    (
        SELECT eid FROM event group by eid HAVING count(eid) > 1
    ) x
)
```

Comment: The cloaked query. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the shortcomings of MySQL.  You can fix it by wrapping the subquery in another subquery:

```
update event
    set repeated = 1
    where eid in (select eid
                  from  (SELECT eid
                         FROM event
                         group by eid
                         HAVING count(eid) > 1
                        ) t
                 );
```